# Ada- what do 'at' and 'range' mean/ do?

Tags: data-structures, record, ada

I am debugging some software that has been written in two parts- one part in C++, and the other part in Ada- which I have never used before.

While reading through some of the Ada code, and looking for variables that contain particlar data, I have found that those variables are used in a `record` in a `for` loop, such as:

```ada
for myRecord use
    record
        eta    at    8    range    0 .. 31;
        ttg    at    16   range    0 .. 63;
    end record;
```

The `at` and `range` are in bold type in the IDE (GPS- GNAT Programming Studio), which I assume means that they are keywords/ have a particular meaning in Ada... Can someone explain to me what this structure is/ does? Do the numbers here have something to do with the amount of memory assigned to the variables/ their memory location?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`eta` starts at bit 0 of byte offset 8 from the start of the record, and continues to bit 31; i.e. it occupies 32 bits starting at byte 8.

Similarly, `ttg` occupies 64 bits starting at byte 16 bit 0.

See [ARM 13.5.1, Record Representation Clauses](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-5-1.html).

Comment: Those are the proof that Ada is better at low-level programming than most other languages, since specifying such bit organization is trivial for Ada.

To complete Simon's answer, you should have a separate declaration for myRecord earlier in the same package.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comment. Yes, I do have a separate declaration for `myRecord`- it comes just before the code that I have quoted, and contains lines such as: `eta : SystemTimeTypes.RelativeTime_Type := 0.0;` inside the structure definition: `type myRecord is record`

Comment: As a follow up question... just below that record definition, there is the line: `for Data_Variant'Size use 129*8;` Is this specifying the size for the whole record (i.e. the total amount of memory that the record and all of its attributes can take up)? Why does Ada need to do this if each of the record's attributes have been given a specific size already? Surely it could just automatically calculate the total memory used for all of the record's attributes?

Comment: @someone2088 Ada doesn't *need* the Size clause; it will allocate enough space for the record.  But sometimes you need more than that.  If the record is one that will, for example, be part of a file record or socket message and the specification of the file or socket says that the data occupies a certain number of bits (or bytes), it's helpful to include the clause to make sure the Ada compiler allocates that number of bits and not less.